# Extract a string and store it as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I extract a string and store it as a variable? I have this URL:

```
http://sub.site.com/WordsHere-t.jpg
```

I want to be able to able to grab just `WordsHere`. It can be any length, it will not always be 9 characters. What's the best way to detect the words after the `/` and before the `-`?

```
var url = "http://sub.site.com/WordsHere-t.jpg";
var getWords = insertRegexHere(url);
document.write(getWords);
```

This should return the string "WordsHere"

Comment: Have you tried any regexes yet?

Comment: `/\/\/.*?\/(.*?)-t.jpg/`? I just love leaning toothpicks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work...

```
var url = "http://sub.site.com/WordsHere-t.jpg";
var getWords = url.match(/.*\/(.*)-/)[1];
```

The regex breaks down like this...

- `.*\/` find everything up to the last single slash
- `(.*)-` CAPTURE everything up to the dash

Here's a fiddle:   [FIDDLE DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/J09fAz3XVT)

And a rubular to show how the Regex works:  [RUBULAR DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/J09fAz3XVT)

*Edit* - and the good thing is it will also work for URLs like this, as the

```
http://sub.site.com/sub1/sub2/WordsHere-t.jpg
```

*Edit2* - I shortened the RegEx...  I think everyone is overthinking this one... it's not necessary to test for the double slashes at the beginning.   Only to find the last slash.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate way, kind of silly, if you don't wanna use regex:

```
var getWords = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.lastIndexOf('-'));
```

This will get you everything between the last / and the last - , but it's dependent on the url structure. If it's always gonna be something like you showed, then you should be just fine, otherwise regex might be a better solution as others suggested.

Comment: Actually, it's not silly. My only doubt is about cases when there are no hyphens in that URL (which my regex kind of covers), but that's easily adjustable. )

Comment: OP said he wants words between `/` and `-`

Comment: @raina77ow Yeah, exactly! It's a starting point I think and depends on what kind of urls he/she has to check.

Comment: @Ani Exactly what this line of code does, or am I mssing something ?

Comment: @G4bri3l you are right on this. You were wrong on your comment. `window.location.pathname` gives only the path after the domain.

Comment: @Ani you're 100% right! I didn't use window.location.pathname to test your solution, my bad ;) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Anee/Vtm77/

```
var path = window.location.pathname; // Get's the path after host url
var arrypath = path.split("-"); // Split's your substring using "-",
console.log(arrypath[0]); // Your expected string
```

Comment: You should read up on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice), and `try this` is not an explanation of your answer.

Comment: Relax, I'm assuming he's only using `document.write` to display the result for debugging purposes.

Comment: That's what I thought :P

Comment: Anyway this doesn't solve the problem, it splits the string in two substrings, first half is everything before "-" and second half is everything after "-", so what you're returning here is http://sub.site.com/WordsHere, which is not what he asked for. He wants just "WordsHere", so this solution might require some extra work to solve the problem.

Comment: @kei that's... that's worse than using `alert` for debugging. =x

Comment: `document.write` is terrible for debugging - removing it changes the way your app works, defeating the purpose.  Use `console.log` instead.

Comment: If the URL is `sub.site.com/WordsHere`, then `location.pathname` by itself would return `/WordsHere`. The only issue really with this solution is if the pathname was longer (e.g. `/sub1/sub2/sub3/WordsHere-t.jpg`) then it would return the entire path and not just the text after the last `/`

Comment: He can fix that using "arrypath[0].substring(arrypath[0].lastIndexOf('/')+1)" and it will always return the exact word!

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want is probably "^[^/]*//[^/]*/([^-.]*)-" and the first capture will be the word you want.